# Why is fgets call ignored if input is of specific size and format?

Tags: c, string

I have the following code written in C

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf1[8];
    char buf2[1024];
    int n;

    fgets(buf1, 6, stdin);
    n = atoi(buf1);

    fgets(buf2, 16, stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever an input with length of more than 4 characters is given to the first fgets, the second fgets exists without waiting for input.

If the first input = 1000, the second fgets hangs and waits for input. However, if the input has 5 characters, 10000 for example, the second fgets exists and the program finishes.

What is the explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem you are having. If I type `1000` + 'Enter', then the program waits for another Enter to be typed.

Comment: @Do you mean "more than 6 characters:?

Comment: `fgets` (and other stdio input functions) mean "get characters from the input stream", not "wait for input" .  Waiting only occurs if there are not already enough characters to satisfy the request .

Comment: Why are you discarding the return value from `fgets()`?  It may read less than you asked for, so you need to make use of that value.

Comment: fgets returns a pointer to the buffer where data was written to. Unfortunately, it does not return the number of characters read. So there is no easy way to know the exact number of characters that were read, especially if the buffer contains '\0' before the actual end of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the input exceeds the specified size minus 1 in a call of fgets as for example

```
char buf1[8];

fgets(buf1, 8, stdin);
```

and the input is

```
1234567
```

then the new line character '\n' that corresponds to the pressed Enter key is not read from the input buffer.

The character array f1 will contain the following content

```
{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '\0' }
```

So the input buffer stays non-empty and the second call of fgets reads the tail  of the input buffer without waiting one more user input.

When the input is less than the specified size minus 1 then the new line character '\n' is read into the character array and the input buffer will be empty.

For example if for this call

```
fgets(buf1, 8, stdin);
```

the user enters

```
123456
```

then the character array will contain

```
{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '\n', '\0' }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you enter 4 characters, then (at least with windows) you read the following 6 characters:

```
1 2 3 4 '\r' '\n'
```

Your buffer is only 6 bytes of size, and a trailing zero byte also has to fit in. So the first call to `fgets()` puts

```
"1234\r\0"
```

into your buffer, then the second call still gets the `\n`, which terminates the line and causes the second `fgets()` to put

```
"\n\0"
```

into the second buffer and to return immediately.
So, you have to account for the line endings ("\r\n" with windows, "\n" with linux) and the zero byte when counting.

Comment: There shouldn't be any `\r` when reading from `stdin` as it is a text stream.